# Tokenizing a string when encountered a newline - Not working newline is not getting recognized

Tags: c, newline

I am trying to tokenize a string when encountered a newline.

```
rest = strdup(value);
while ((token = strtok_r(rest,"\n", &rest))) {
       snprintf(new_value, MAX_BANNER_LEN + 1, "%s\n", token);
}
```

where 'value' is a string say, "This is an example\nHere is a newline"

But the above function is not tokenizing the 'value' and the 'new_value' variable comes as it is i.e. "This is an example\nHere is a newline".

Any suggestions to overcome this?

Thanks,
Poornima

Comment: Don't you get warnings? `strtok_r` takes a string of possible separators (`"\n"`), not a single char (`'\n'`).

Comment: I edited the question above. I also tried using the "\n" at the first time.

Comment: And the `rest` parameter is overwritten by `strtok_r`. It is just interal state so that the function is re-entrant. Don't use the sme variable for the string and for `rest`. Also, `strtok_r` expects `NULL` on subsequent tokenizations of the same string.

Comment: Tried doing      token = strtok(rest,"\n");
    while (token != NULL) {
          snprintf(new_value, MAX_BANNER_LEN + 1, "%s\n", token);
          token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    } . Still not recognizing \n

Comment: Also tried this  token = strtok(rest,"\"\n");
    while (token != NULL) {
          snprintf(new_value, MAX_BANNER_LEN + 1, "%s\n", token);
          token = strtok(NULL, "\"\n");
    }
It also did not work. Any help to make '\n' character recongized ? I also tried giving string input as "This is an example\r\nHere is a newline".

Comment: Please don't post code in comments (the formatting is bad in comments). Edit your question and post code and what have you tried in the question. Also please add `#include`s and `int main()` and all the relevant definitions that are needed to reproduce the problem you are having. How is `value` defined? How is `rest` define? How is `new_value` defined? What is `MAX_BANNER_LEN`? Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There are many examples on how to use `strtok` available online.

Answer (score 0):

Several things going on with your code:

- `strtok` and `strtok_r` take the string to tokenize as first parameter. Subsequent tokenizations of the same string should pass `NULL`. (It is okay to tokenize the same string with different delimiters.)
- The second parameter is a string of possible separators. In your case you should pass `"\n"`. (`strtok_r` will treat stretches of the characters as single break. That means that tokenizing `"a\n\n\nb"` will produce two tokens.)
- The third parameter to `strtok_r` is an internal parameter to the function. It will mark where the next tokenization should start, but you need not use it. Just define a `char *` and pass its address.
- Especially, don't repurpose the source string variable as state. In your example, you will lose the handle to the `strdup`ed string, so that you cannot free it later, as you should.
- It is not clear how you determine that your tokenization "doesn't work". You print the token to the same char buffer repeatedly. Do you want to keep only the part after the last newline? In that case, use `strchrr(str, '\n')`. If the result isn't `NULL` it is your "tail". If it is `NULL` the whole string is your tail.

Here's how tokenizing a string could work:

```
char *rest = strdup(str);
char *state;
char *token = strtok_r(rest, "\n", &state);

while (token) {
    printf("'%s'\n", token);

    token = strtok_r(NULL, "\n", &state);
}

free(rest);
```